# Svelte awaited block how to modify an array value of promise?

Tags: svelte

I am fetching and displaying a list of notes(cards). Each one of them has a delte button with calls the delete function.

The delete function takes the list and index and pops the element and from the list.

The problem is it always pop the last item of the array.
Also please tell if there is a better way to do this

```
<script>
  let gusername = null;
  let gresponse;
  let notes = {};
  function handleNotesGet() {
    notes = getNote();
  }

  async function deleteNote(nlist, index, nid) {
    // var response = await fetch(
    //   "http://localhost:3000/api/user/" + gusername + "/note/" + nid,
    //   {
    //     method: "delete",
    //     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    //   }
    // );
    // gresponse.innerHTML = await response.text();
    console.log(index);
    nlist.pop(index);
    notes = nlist;
  }

  async function getNote() {
    console.log("Username", gusername);
    var response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/user/" + gusername, {
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    });
    if (response.status == 200) {
      return JSON.parse(await response.text());
    } else {
      throw Error(await response.text());
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="column">
      <input
        bind:value={gusername}
        class="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type username" />
    <div class="control">
      <button on:click={handleNotesGet} class="button is-info">
        Get Notes
      </button>
    </div>
    <br />
  <div>
    <code bind:this={gresponse} />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Promise block begins here -->
    {#await notes}
      <p>...fetching</p>
    {:then docs}
    <!-- An array of objects is returned -->
      {#each docs as doc, i}
      <!--Display a card-->
        <div class="box">
          <article class="media">
            <div class="media-content">
              <div class="content">
                <p>
                  <strong>{doc.title}</strong>
                  <small>@{doc.uid}</small>
                  <br />
                  <strong>{i}</strong>
                  <strong>{doc._id}</strong>
                  <!-- <small>{new Date(doc.dateCreated).toUTCString()}</small> -->
                  <br />
                   {doc.content}
                </p>
              </div>
              <nav class="level is-mobile">
                <div class="level-left">
                <!-- bind the delete butto with func -->
                  <button
                    on:click={() => {
                      deleteNote(docs, i, doc._id);
                    }}
                    class="button is-small is-danger">
                    ⌫
                  </button>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      {/each}
    {:catch error}
      <p style="color:red">{error.message}</p>
    {/await}
    <!--  -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `arr.pop()` doesn't take arguments

Use `arr.splice(start, deleteCount)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. been doing a lot of python in college and now I was trying to do the same in JS. :/